# How to set datepicker dialog to tommorows date, in android?

Tags: android

I want to set the date picker dialog to tomorrows date also to restrict the date to show only next 6 months in android date picker dialog ,can anybody please help me out..

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:

            DatePickerDialog dpDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            DatePicker datePicker = dpDialog.getDatePicker();

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();//get the current day

            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

            Date newDate = calendar.getTime();
            dpDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(newDate.getTime());
            return dpDialog;
        case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
            return new TimePickerDialog(this,
                    mTimeSetListener, mHour, mMinute, false);
    }
    return null;
}

  private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener =
        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                  int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                mYear = year;
                mMonth = monthOfYear;
                mDay = dayOfMonth;
                updateDisplay();
            }
        };


private void updateDisplay() {

    mDateDisplay.setText(
            new StringBuilder()
                    // Month is 0 based so add 1
                    .append(pad(mMonth + 1)).append("-")
                    .append(pad(mDay)).append("-")
                    .append(mYear).append(" "));
}
```

Comment: Please share some more code or links what you tried alread

Comment: Thanks for your replay,here is the code , now am able to show the tommorrows date on the datepicker dialog also i want to show only next 6months dates , can  you please help on this...

Comment: Same way, just use `setMaxDate()` aswell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try 
dpDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(calendarWith6MonthsAdded.getTime());